# Error : 'Requested value 'baseline' was not found.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

When I Uploading An Excel File (.xlsx) Using Epplus Method In Asp.Net C#.
**My Code :**
*

```
> if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
>         {
>             if (Path.GetExtension(FileUploadControl.FileName) == ".xlsx")
>             {
>                 ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(FileUploadControl.FileContent);
>                 ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
>                 workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Year";
>                 workSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Month";
>                 workSheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Date";
>                 workSheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Member Id";
>                 workSheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Member Name";
>                 workSheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Flat Type";
>                 workSheet.Cells[1, 7].Value = "Previous Unit";
>                 workSheet.Cells[1, 8].Value = "New Unit";
>                 workSheet.Cells[1, 9].Value = "Rate";
>                 DataTable table = new DataTable();
>                 foreach (var FirstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column])
>                 {
>                     table.Columns.Add(FirstRowCell.Text);
>                 }
>                 for (var RowNumber = 2; RowNumber <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; RowNumber++)
>                 {
>                     var Row = workSheet.Cells[RowNumber, 1, RowNumber, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column];
>                     var NewRow = table.NewRow();
>                     foreach (var cell in Row)
>                     {
>                         NewRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
>                     }
>                     table.Rows.Add(NewRow);
>                 }
>                 ExcelGridView.DataSource = table;
>                 ExcelGridView.DataBind();
>             }
>         }
```

*

Comment: Explain more about your issue and conditions. which line this happens? plus have you tracked your code and point break point?

Comment: Line :ExcelWorksheet workSheet =package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

Comment: Did you confirm that `package` is not `null`?  Did you confirm that there are actually **2** worksheets?  Remember that **package.Workbook.Worksheets** is a 0-based collection so using an index of 1 like you are is going to try to get the second sheet.

Comment: Thanks For All Of Your Comment. But I Solve That Error By Myself...........